# Origin of correlated multi-muon events underground

Tags: cosmic-rays

The flux of muons underground (above ~10 km water equivalent) are primarily produced in the atmosphere by cosmic rays. There is an abundance of literature detailing the flux, spectrum, and angular distribution as a function of depth. Though sparser, there are also measurements and some parameterizations of muon burst events, such as measured by the MACRO detector https://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.56.1407 .

My question: are correlated multi-muon events observed underground primarily from

1. multiple muons produced in the atmosphere by the same cosmic ray?
2. showers produced in the rock by an isolated muon?
3. something else?

Comment: AFAIK, muon scattering in rock/soil is basically 0, so probably all muons you find are the secondaries from an air shower.